# Width of the content inside `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`

Tags: width

Is there a way to know the width used by a paragraph ? In the following code, I would like to adjust the line to be a little bigger than the text *"Location: Somewhere over the rainbow"*.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{center}
\rule[0.4ex]{\linewidth}{0.2ex}

DS: Probability \& Geometry

Location: Somewhere over the rainbow

\rule[0.4ex]{\linewidth}{0.2ex}
\end{center}

Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can measure the width using something like: `\setbox0\hbox{Location: Somewhere over the rainbow}` the width is then `\wd0`. Note that this is not expandable and you should evaluate `\wd0` close to the `\setbox` because it will be invalid if something else uses that box.

Comment: Let's see my comment to the answer of Latain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \midrule
DS: Probability \& Geometry             \\
Location: Somewhere over the rainbow    \\
    \midrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}

Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, ...

\end{document}
```

**edit:**
if you like to change `midrule` thickness, you can add option with thickness as for example `\midrule[3pt]`. also for top rule you can use `\toprule` or `\toprule[2pt]`. for more details see documentation of package `booktabs`.

rules are longer than text for `\tabcolsep` on each side of table cell. its default size is `6pt`, but you can change size with `\setlength\tabcolsep{<desired length>}`. An example considering this is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{12pt}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \toprule[2pt]
DS: Probability \& Geometry             \\
Location: Somewhere over the rainbow    \\
    \midrule[3pt]
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}

Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to set a factor, say 20%, of overshoot,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\toprule[2pt]
\makebox[1.20\width]{% 20% longer rules
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    DS: Probability \& Geometry \\
    Location: Somewhere over the rainbow
  \end{tabular}%
}\\
\midrule[3pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to set the width using a factor, and thickness using absolute dimension ?

Comment: width of `midrule`? for example: \midrule[1pt]`, length of `midrule`? it is longer than text for `\tabcolsep` on each side. you can change it by for example `\setlength\tabcolsep{12pt} `(default value of `\tabcolsep` is 6pt).

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a method for stating the amount of overshoot as a factor of the width of the text.

Comment: @eqreg, thank you. i should confess, that i didn't understood, what op means with " set the width using a factor" ... now have  sense even for me :-)

Comment: Sorry for my english. I'm a french frog. ;-) Thanks a lot. This seems to be the simpler way to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `\widthof{}` from the usepackage calc like: `\rule[0.4ex]{\widthof{Location: Somewhere over the rainbow}}{0.2ex}`

Comment: This can donne the job but I will need then to calculate a maximum regarding each line of my text. Is there an easy way to do that ?